# I have a Kyocera ECOSYS printer displaying error C7403. How do I fix the machine?

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I have a Kyocera ECOSYS M6026cdn printer displaying the error:

```
Machine failure.
Call service.
    C7403
```

Studying the error it related to the Magenta developer being incorrect/incompatible. I assume this means failed as the part was never changed. On replacing the part, the error does not go away. How do I fix this printer error?

**Further information:**
I am researching the relative pinouts of the main board "engine PWB". The connector to the developer is a ground, a 3.3V supply and a sense voltage I understand for density measurement. Connector YC34 on the "engine PWB" connects to the drum PWB to which the drums and developers are connected. In service, the sensing voltages are:
TS-C: 0.06 V
TS-Y: 0.05 V
TS-M: 2.01 V
TS-K: 1.20 V

I'm perhaps a little surprised to see two of these be different to the other two, if only the Magenta developer is 'bad'. But the M and K are both showing high values (corresponding to high or low density? Density of what?)

Hopefully I'm getting closer to understanding the problem. The whole unit was cleaned out prior to the error occurring, so I don't know what that might have contributed. But a replacement Magenta developer has not resolved the issue.

Comment: A google for "kyocera printer C7403" suggests to me that cleaning the associated electrical contacts might help. Beyond that, actually do the search to see the other options ;)

Comment: It's how I knew it was the magenta developer..!

Comment: OK, so did you try cleaning the electrical contacts? Otherwise, as you've seen, it's a case of "replace the developing unit" or "replace the engine PWB and check for correct operation". Either of the latter may, sadly, be more expensive than buying a new printer.

Comment: Would you say if I replace both and still find an issue that I should replace the printer, there is nothing left to repair? I guess I'm hoping for diagnostic information that goes beyond the service manual

Comment: The usual advice is that this error is about the Magenta developing unit. Check the connection between the printer and the developing unit and restart the printer. If the error will not go away after that, you will have to replace the Magenta developing unit. If the error still will not go away, you will need to replace the engine power board.